# php singleton keeps calling itself twice in an autoloader class

Tags: php, singleton, spl

I made an autoloader class that works as intended, but i have noticed an odd behavior. When I echo out the results of the classes found that are passed to the method that handles the `spl_autoload_register()` function. I am seeing that I have doubles. Like if the script is called twice, and because its a singleton the data builds 2 arrays in my case.

I am using this method to create my singleton

```
public static function init()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance))
        self::$instance = new self();

    return self::$instance;
}
```

I then have the constructor set to private. I have gone thru each method debugging trying to see where it appears to create a clone of itself.

I suspect that my classes and class for that matter is being cloned somewhere in the spl_autoload_register() function.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the __clone function accordingly?

Comment: Can you post the complete class code?

Comment: okays, posted. If i run this as non singleton instance then it won't clone itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the constructor print out something. Just to see if it is really being called more than once.
You are using two autloaders right?
i would set up sp_autoload_register at the very start of the application (maybe the index.php) and register all required autoloaders.
But test if the contructor is being called more than once first.

// first i would change this:

```
private static $instance = null;
```

// the init function

```
public static function init() {
   if (self::$instance === null) {
     self::$instance = new Autoload();
   }

   return self::$instance;
}
```

Comment: I set a counter and had it run up everytime the class is called. and sure enough i get it +1. You want me to put the spl_autoload_register where? I am calling this script once in my index.php already. I updated my post with my updated code too

Comment: I am not sure about this inside the register method: spl_autoload_register(array ('Autoloader', 'loadClass'));

Comment: hmmm, i originally had it set to `spl_auto_register('self::autoload()')` before i went the singleton route.

Comment: do this: private function __construct() {
   print "hello autoload world";      
}

Comment: This should only come up once. If this only comes up once the singleton is working.

Comment: i just waved hello to the autoload world. I am finding that everything is ok UNTIL i get to the register() method. If you compile this your self and echo something within that method then it will come out twice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7754/discussion-between-busypeoples-and-eli)